# What is the DB2 LEFT equivalent in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I was using the below query to pull data with first char as Numeric for DB2. How can I get same results from Oracle DB?

```
select * 
from ABC.App_v
Where (left(prefix_cd, 1) IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr()`:

```
where substr(prefix_cd, 1, 1) between '0' and '9'
```

Or, if you don't want to use a function, just use string comparisons:

```
where prefix_cd >= '0' and prefix_ce < ':'
```

Admittedly, this is abstruse.  The colon follows "9" in the ASCII character codes.

Comment: Thank you, @Gordon that helped

Comment: Wouldn't `where prefix_cd >= '0' and prefix_ce <= '9'` be less abstruse then?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You'd have to use `<= '999999....99999' (in the length of the column). Your predicate doesn't match `'99'`.